# How to add and remove the active class on the various sections of my HTML nav bar using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a nav bar that has four different section names of the webpage. When I click on one of the section names, I want it to be active (highlighted) and I want the previous active section name to no longer be active. I have been trying many different JavaScript functions and code, but have not been able to succeed. If anyone can look at my code and let me know what I am missing or doing wrong, that would be amazing. Please let me know if you have any questions with my code or problem, I will be happy to answer. Thank you.

HTML Code (navbar.html):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary fixed-top" id="sideNav">
            <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">
                <span class="d-block d-lg-none">Joseph Smith</span>
                <span class="d-none d-lg-block"><img class="img-fluid img-profile rounded-circle mx-auto mb-2" src="{% static 'img/joseph_headshot.jpg' %}"alt="..." /></span>
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger active" href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#education">Education</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#experience">Experience</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

JavaScript Code (script.js):

```
responsiveNavItems.map(function (responsiveNavItem) {
        responsiveNavItem.addEventListener('click', () => {
            const curr_active = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar-nav").getElementsByTagName('li').getElementsByClassName(".active");
            curr_active[0].className = curr_active[0].className.replace(" active", "");
            responsiveNavItem.className += " active";
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem may be the period before "active" when looking for elements with that class name.

Try this...

```
responsiveNavItems.map(function (responsiveNavItem) {
  responsiveNavItem.addEventListener('click', nav_link_click);
});

function nav_link_click() {
  const curr_active = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-nav').getElementsByTagName('li').getElementsByClassName('active');
  curr_active[0].classList.remove('active');
  this.classList.add('active');
}
```

Comment: I think it may have to do with my javascript file not being found or recognized. I am getting the error "net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)" when I look at the developer tools of my website. The only javascript file I have is the script.js file. The code that I have in my html file is: <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Core theme JS-->
        <!--<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>-->
        <script src="nicks_website/static/theme/js/scripts.js"></script>

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with the way I am calling the scripts.js file in my HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use querySelector(). It allows you to find the first element that matches one or more CSS selectors. You can call the querySelector() method on the document or any HTML element.

```
function myFunction(e) {
  var elements = document.querySelector(".active");
  if(elements !==null){
   elements.classList.remove("active");
  }
 e.target.className = "active";
}
```